# Calculate majority voting based on hour and day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame having columns `tweet_text`, `date`, `time` and `sentiments` and these columns have following values

```
tweet_text    date         time       sentiments
tweet1        2021-08-16   11:53:37   positive  
tweet2        2021-08-16   02:44:04   neutral
tweet3        2021-08-16   02:44:02   neutral
tweet4        2021-08-16   02:47:02   neutral
tweet5        2021-08-16   02:50:00   negative
tweet6        2021-08-17   05:20:46   positive
tweet7        2021-08-17   06:01:00   positive
tweet8        2021:08:17   06:20:00   positive
tweet9        2021:08:17   07:05:00   negative
tweet10       2021:08:17   07:20:21   negative
```

It can be reproduced using

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tweet_text': ['tweet1', 'tweet2', 'tweet3', 'tweet4', 'tweet5', 'tweet6', 'tweet7, 'tweet8', 'tweet9', 'tweet10'], 
                   'date': [2021-08-16, 2021-08-16, 2021-08-16, 2021-08-16, 2021-08-16, 2021-08-17, 2021-08-17, 2021-08-17,2021-08-17, 2021-08-17], 
                   'time': [11:53:37, 02:44:04, 02:44:02, 02:47:02'02:50:00', '05:20:46' '06:01:00', '06:20:00', '07:05:00', '07:20:21'], 
                   'sentiments': ['positive', 'neutral', 'neutral', 'neutral', 'negative', 'positive', 'positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative']})
```

I need to calculate sentiments based on majority voting of each hour and each day. I need two different DataFrames as output. One for days majority voting, such as

```
Date         Majority_Sentiment
2021-08-16   neutral
2021-08-17   positive
```

Second DataFrame for hourly Majority voting, which can be as following

```
Date         Hour    Majority_Sentiment
2021-08-16   11:00   positive   
2021-08-16   02:00   neutral
2021-08-17   05:00   positive
2021:08:17   06:00   positive
2021:08:17   07:00   negative
```

I know `df.mode()` can be used calculate it but how can I implement it in my scenario? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion I have revised my question.

Comment: Super, can you add expected ouput from input data?

Comment: I have updated my question and added expected output, please have a look. Thank you

Comment: I am bit confused. First there is only 3 rows of data sample, so it is bad sample here, because not possible clearly see what need in ouput, small data, so same number of rows in input data and ouput. another problem is from input data not matched ouput, there are not `12:00`, `13:00` and `2021-08-17` in second ouput. Is possible create better input (e.g. 10 rows)/ ouput data in question?

Comment: Super sample data, so added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function for [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html), and because possible returned multiple values is selected only first by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]
df1 = df.groupby('date')['sentiments'].apply(f).reset_index(name='Majority_Sentiment')
print (df1)
         date Majority_Sentiment
0  2021-08-16            neutral
1  2021-08-17           positive
```

For second ouput convert `time` column to datetimes and then to custom format `HH:00` by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and group by both - column `date` and `time` series:

```
times = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%H:00')
df2 = (df.groupby(['date', times], sort=False)['sentiments'].apply(f)
         .reset_index(name='Majority_Sentiment'))
print (df2)
```

Another similar solution is assign back times:

```
df['time']= pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%H:00')
df2 = (df.groupby(['date', 'time'], sort=False)['sentiments'].apply(f)
         .reset_index(name='Majority_Sentiment'))
print (df2)


         date   time Majority_Sentiment
0  2021-08-16  11:00           positive
1  2021-08-16  02:00            neutral
2  2021-08-17  05:00           positive
3  2021-08-17  06:00           positive
4  2021-08-17  07:00           negative
```

Answer (score -1):

1. generate small dataset

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random


n = 1000
rawdata = pd.DataFrame({'tweet_text': [f'tweet{i}' for i in range(n)],
                        'date': random.choices(
                            [(datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for days in
                             range(10)], k=n),
                        'time': [(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=i)).strftime('%H:%M:%S') for i in
                                 random.choices(range(40000), k=n)],
                        'sentiments': random.choices(population=['positive', 'neutral', 'foo', 'bar'], k=n)
                        })
rawdata
```

2. cal the result

```py
def cal_majority(x):
    "get the most frequency of x"
    x = np.array(x)
    (index, value) = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    majority_str = index[np.argmax(value)]
    return majority_str


def cal_second_value(x):
    "get the second frequency of x"
    x = np.array(x)
    (index, value) = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    second_str = index[np.argsort(value)[-(np.shape(value)[0] - 1)]]
    return second_str


rawdata.groupby(['date']).agg(
    majority_sentiment=('sentiments', cal_majority),
    second_sentiment = ('sentiments', cal_second_value)
)
```

show result:
[image]

3. cal more with time:

```
data2 = rawdata.copy()
data2['time'] = data2['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S').strftime("%H:00"))
data2.groupby(['date', 'time']).agg(
    majority_sentiment=('sentiments', cal_majority),
    second_sentiment = ('sentiments', cal_second_value)
).reset_index()
```

[image]